# fetching URL using react-redux works but if i refresh the page, it won't work

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux

There are two problems that Im facing currently, Im trying to do a basic GET request and it works just fine, but the problem lies when I refresh the page

For your information I'm doing a react-redux server rendering.

The url that the react-redux trying to consume is '/courses'

**The Problems**

1) `'/courses'` is the url for the server and for fetching in react-redux, and it works perfectly fine, in terms of navigation. For example from `'/'` (home page) to `'/courses'` page

it shows all the json data perfectly but when I refresh the page, it will show all the json data

**Example**

Home page

[image]

**Courses Page**

[image]

it shows perfectly but when I refresh the page, it shows all the json data not from the react-redux.

[image]

I know you guys will say that just change the URL from `'/courses'` -> `'/api/courses'` I did that and I get my second problem

2) Which is

> ReferenceError: fetch is not defined, whenever I refresh the page

Here's the code

**Routes**

```
import React from 'react';
import { IndexRoute, Route } from 'react-router';
import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Course from './components/Course';

export default function getRoutes(store) {

  return (
    <Route path="/" component={App}>
      <IndexRoute component={Home}  />
      <Route path='/courses' component={Course}  />
    </Route>

  );


}
```

Action

```
export function getCourses() {
  return (dispatch) => {

    return fetch('/courses', {
      method: 'get',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json().then((json) => {
          dispatch({
            type: 'GET_COURSES',
            courses: json.courses
          });
        })
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**Main.js**

```
import 'whatwg-fetch';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import getRoutes from './routes';

const store = configureStore(window.INITIAL_STATE);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={ getRoutes(store)} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

And after that I just dispatch the action to the component which is `Course.js` which will render the component.

I'm really new to react-redux, and hope you guys could help me

Comment: So you are using SSR (Server Side Rendering)? Can you show the code where you are using `getRoutes`? Probably you are not setting up the routes correctly on the server side, also I would recommend you to move your API to `/api/courses` to avoid conflicts with the UI.

Comment: I just updated the question, I called it in the main.js